# Error: Access is denied , Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {36D27C48-A1E8-11D3-BA55-00C04F72F325}

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, office-interop

I'm developing an asp.net mvc web app that export data to MS Project,
when I run my app locally or server from visual studio every thing is ok.

When I run my app on IIS i have the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {36D27C48-A1E8-11D3-BA55-00C04F72F325} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I have followed the instruction in [these](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6229334e-d5ef-4016-9e7e-1c8718be8d43/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-vbnet?forum=netfxbcl) site,

> Give the user Remote Launch and Remote Activation permissions in dcomcnfg.  Right-click My Computer-> Properties Under COM Security,
>    click "Edit Limits" for both sections. Give the user you want remote
>    access, remote launch, and remote activation. Then go to DCOM Config,
>    find "Windows Management Instrumentation", and give the user you want
>    Remote Launch and Remote Activation.

but still doesn't work.

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

---

I have found the solution:

I have set the iis pool as integrated and to run as 'loocal system'.

Comment: I tried the same but now I am getting error:

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\web-site\\OrderReport.xls'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640623/microsoft-excel-cannot-access-the-file-there-are-several-possible-reasons but no luck.

Already gave permission.

I am using Windows server 2012 R2 and Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010

Comment: Have you tried MS Excel DCOM lunch for local user?