# Why do WSH JScript child processes fail when script is launched remotely?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, psexec

On a Windows Server 2012 R2 standard machine (AWS EC2 instance) I am using PsExec to start a process on a similar remote computer, supplying user credentials.  The process fails in various ways that make me suspect permissions: two AWS CLI commands fail with codes 255 (ses sendemail) or 2 (s3 cp) and Excel refuses to save a file, complaining that there is no disk space.

If I log on to the second machine using the same credentials and run the same .bat file to start the process, it all runs as expected.  The process is a WSH JScript and runs invisibly under cscript.exe with its ouput redirected to a file.

I ran a SET command via both methods to see whether the environments were different.  There were four differences, none of which seem relevant:

- local run has CLIENTNAME=COMPAQ, remote does not have that variable
- local has SESSIONNAME variable (from running via mstsc), remote does not
- TEMP and TMP have extra subdirectory \3 appended on local but not remote.  Both versions end with directories which show as read-only in explorer.
- local PATH includes C:\USERS\*username*\.dnx\bin but remote has %USERPROFILE% instead of *username*. There is no such directory in either case.

Today I tried process monitor (thanks @GamerJ5 for the suggestion) and saved all the Excel events from a successful local run and a failed remote-start run.  Filtering out SUCCESS still left a few thousand results in each case, with no obvious clue as to which of the many failures might be important.

Can anyone suggest what types of request / result might be worth further investigation, or anything else I can look at?

Comment: -i is only relevant if you're using -s. 
Have you tried running procmon while reproducing the behavior?
Locally on that computer with the same credentials does this work correctly?
What is Windows 2014 R2?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else: it turns out that there was a red herring in the question; the failures of the two AWS commands were indirect consequences of the Excel failure.  That was a consequence of ignoring Microsoft's "Don't run Office on a server" advice (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757), but a suggested work-around that I found on another post ([Microsoft Excel cannot access the file "...". There are several possible reasons Windows Server 2008 R2 with Microsoft Office 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640623/microsoft-excel-cannot-access-the-file-there-are-several-possible-reasons)) worked in this case: create the directory that Excel expects to find at Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop.