# Unable to run .vbs from Windows PowerShell in jenkins job

Tags: powershell, jenkins, vbscript

I am trying to use build-->windows power-shell option in Jenkins job and calling the following code:

```
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\
cscript create.vbs
```

My `create.vbs` has the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Remove the following line to open Excel in the background
xlApp.Visible = true
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\excelname.xlsm",0, True)
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

But I am getting the following error in console of failed job in jenkins:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\create.vbs(8, 1) 
Microsoft Excel: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 
    'C:\Users\username\Desktop\excelname.xlsm'.
```

There are several possible reasons:

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

My `create.vbs` and excel sheet are at the same location, none of the excel workbook is opened and I am able to run successfully `cscript create.vbs` through Windows PowerShell directly.

Comment: Your script does not understand `<username>` and `<excelname>` in the workbook filepath that you are trying to open. Have you tried to run the vbs file independently? Does it run?

Comment: Yes, the vbs file runs independently as mentioned above "I am able to run successfully "cscript create.vbs" through windows power shell /cmd directly"

Comment: [Please look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640623/microsoft-excel-cannot-access-the-file-there-are-several-possible-reasons). This will help you. This is not a jenkins error though.

Comment: Are you running jenkins as service ? If so, try running it from CLI and test it again.

Comment: I have tried changing the DCOM settings  and in jenkins.service selected the option “Allow service to interact with desktop".Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Launch a slave in cmd and label the jenins job to run on this new slave.It works! the issue was because jenkins was running as a service and was unable to access excel being a desktop application.